# How to get white paint stains out of black silgranit sink

Tags: paint, sink, cleaning, stain

The other day a painter came to paint a wall white and he washed his tools and buckets in my black kitchen sink that's made out of [silgranit](https://www.blanco.com/us-en/sinks/materials/silgranit-sink-collections/). I don't know the composition of the material but it's got a rough surface, if not porous, and it looks like small white flecks of paint got embedded in it.

How can I get the wall paint out of the sink's surface?

Comment: #1: pick up the phone, #2: dial your painter, #3 "hey bozo, get your dumb @$$ back over here and fix this mess". The alternative may involve something like a "brush cleaner" which will soften the dried paint, but might not be friendly to your plumbing in large volumes or high concentrations.

Comment: Before i tried any harsh chemicals or abrasives that might scratch, id try scrubbing it with something like a 3M brillow pad (the green ones not the meatal or sandpaper ones).

Comment: I was thinking a porous surface would be very bad for a kitchen sink! So I went to the website, sure enough, it states that it is **non**-porous. You may want to check the Blanco website for cleaning advice.

Comment: Step #3 in @brhans' answer _might_ include the painter paying to have a plumber replace the whole sink if he can't get it clean or further damages it in his attempts to do so. Photographic evidence before he returns would be wise.

Comment: Before trying anything drastic, I would fill the sink with water and detergent and let it soak overnight.  Maybe several nights.  Hopefully the paint will soften.  Time is your friend in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Base is acrylic, so you should not use chemicals for paint removing, like lacquer thinner. Some strong cleaning staff, like sodium hydroxide.

Comment: Maybe polyester; same advice.

Comment: @blacksmith37 The post has a link. Technical info said acrylic. Polyester soft, melamine is used for similar.